# Lambda calculus problem

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I gotta solve a lambda calculus problem. I reached certain point and I don´t know how to continue:

```
h f x = \g -> g (f x g)

(h::a1 f::a2 x::a3)::a4 = (\g -> g::a5 (f::a2 x::a3 g::a5)::a6)::a4

a1 = a2 -> a3 -> a4
a2 = a3 -> a5 -> a6
a5 = a6 -> a4

a1 = (a3 -> a5 -> a4) -> a3 -> a4
a1 = (a3 -> (a6->a4) -> a4) -> a3 -> a4
```

is there any way of finishing?. I use "a1,a2,a3..." to represent a type for the element or function. For example, 1::Int, 2.4::Float, f::a1, x::a3 and so on. I don´t know if it is clear enought...

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am pretty sure most people do not understand the notation you use here. Since they cannot grasp what the problem is (and what your solution so far is), they can't help you.

Comment: Ok, I explain a little just in case. I hope, ppl can undestand it somehow better :)

Comment: You're using `::` for type annotations and `\x -> ...` for lambdas, the combination of which is, to my knowledge, unique to Haskell and things closely related to it. Given that, why not just type `:t \f x -> \g -> g (f x g)` into GHCi and see what it tells you?

Comment: Presumably because the whole exercise is testing his ability to understand and work out types, and is clearly worthwhile.

Comment: Another reminder to accept the answer below. Click the green tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a mistake. `g=a5: a6 -/-> a4.` Your brackets are wrong on line 2.

```
h f x = \g -> g (f x g)

(h::a1 f::a2 x::a3)::a4 = (\g -> (g::a5 (f::a2 x::a3 g::a5)::a6)::a7)::a4

a1 = a2 -> a3 -> a4
a2 = a3 -> a5 -> a6
a5 = a6 -> a7
a4 = a5 -> a7

a1 = (a3 -> a5 -> a6) -> a3 -> a4
a1 = (a3 -> (a6->a7) -> a6) -> a3 -> a5 -> a7
a1 = (a3 -> (a6->a7) -> a6) -> a3 -> (a6 -> a7) -> a7
```

That is therefore the correct type for h (you can check if you're paranoid just by typing `fun h f x = (fn g => g (f x g) )` into an SML prompt and getting the exact same result; same goes for Haskell with appropriate syntax). h is a polymorphic function, so all the a's are arbitrary, but express the relationship between the types of h's argument and the argument of the result of applying h and so on.

Comment: Brilliant!! Anyway, How did you get a4 = a5 -> a7?. I can´t find that relation anywhere. Thank you so much!!

Comment: When h is defined, you see the value that's returned? It's `\g->g(f x g)`. That's a function, which takes one argument (let's call him g), and returns `g(f x h)`. That's exactly what the statement says: a4 is a function which takes an argument of type a5 (what we called g's type), and returns a function of type a7 (which is what I labelled the output of g with; that's the one you forgot to label).

Comment: By the way, the three types left at the end, a3, a6, a7 are the only ones left because they're the only functions which are applied to anything, so we can't say anything more about their type. That's how we know when we're done.

Comment: PS. It's good to go back and click to 'accept' answers to your questions that have been answered. Keeps the pool of unanswered questions down and keeps answerers happy.